# Why am i getting callBack is not a function in my React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a callBack function in my async code but I am getting the error "TypeError: callBack is not a function". What am I doing wrong? I created the callBack function separately and passed it to the async function as a parameter then called it my useEffect.

```
function callBack() {
    setTopicLoaded(true); 
}

 

 function fetchGroupTopic(groupAdminId, callBack) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getTopic());
    try {
      const myTopic = [];
      if (groupAdminId) {
        const response = firestore
          .collection("topic")
          .where("adminId", "==", groupAdminId);
        const data = await response.get();
        data.docs.forEach((item) => {
          let id = item.id;
          let data = item.data();

          myTopic.push({ id, ...data });
        });
        callBack(); // the error is coming from this line //
        dispatch(setGroupTopic(myTopic));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(getTopicFailure());
    }
  };
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (myGroup.length) {
      fetchGroupTopic(myGroup[0].adminId, callBack);
    }

    
  }, [id, submitted, myGroup]);
```

Comment: Is `callBack` defined in scope of the component, or passed in, to be available for the `useEffect` to pass to `fetchGroupTopic`? Can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive component code example?

Comment: Also,`fetchGroupTopic` seems to be a thunk that you would need to `dispatch` in the `useEffect` call. What you're trying to do, setting a component state from within a thunk, is an anti-pattern and should be avoided. Just represent the topic loading state inside the store, retrieve it with a selector and add that to `useEffect` 's dependency list.